# String text to long value

Tags: string, blackberry, java-me, long-integer

Well, thats it!
I need to convert a string text (like"Hrd$457"), into a long value.
The blackberry IDE has a button that do it, but i need do this by code.
Please note that the string is alpha numeric.

THX!

NOTE:
Sorry if my question was not really clear. The IDE button that im talkin about converts the entire string in a long value that makes that string a unique number. The BlackBerry documentation says:

"To create a unique long key, in the BlackBerry® Integrated Development Environment, type a string value.
com.rim.samples.docs.userinfo
Right-click the string and click Convert ‘com.rim.samples.docs.userinfo’ to long."

So, i need to do exactly the same but by code.

I really appreciate your help buddies, and thanks so much for trying to help.

Comment: What does Hrd$ signify?  What would your expected output be?  457 or something else?

Comment: @JustinKSU Yes! that's what i expect. Like I said, BlackBerry IDE do that. I mean, if the text is HGF&78KoL, it will generate something like 0987L

Comment: In your example why would it return 0987 and not 78?

Comment: Is just an example...It doesn't return the numbers of the string, it must return the long value of the entire string.

Comment: @FilipeDev.- IMO, your question does not make any sense to me.  Please tell us what button in the Blackberry IDE you are talking about ... and maybe we can figure out what your are asking.  (FWIW - I suspect that the string is an identifier for a field widget or something in an blackberry app's UI ... and he wants to extract the value that the user has entered into the field.)

Comment: @FilipeDev.- As an aside, `"Hrd$457"` and `"HGF&78KoL"` are not alphanumeric because they both contain characters that are neither letters or digits.

Comment: You really need to clarify your question, so far it doesn't make any sense - there's no concept of "the long value of a string" (if you don't mean hashing)

Comment: The BlackBerry IDE does hashing to generate unique keys to communicate events on the device.  It turns any highlighted string into a long constant.  This is what is meant by "the IDE has a button that do it".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just looking for **a number** constant for a string you can do the following.

```
String str = "asdfasdf345asdfasdf";
int asInt = str.hashCode();
long asLong = (long) asInt;
```

Comment: Thanks man!! i'd never thought that!! that solve my problem. BTW i suppose there is a possibility that the numbers be repeated for different strings, do you know the probability of this?

Comment: Yes.  Two strings can have the same number.  This is because a String can contain more bytes than an int can hold.  If you wanted to convert a String into a long that is unique for every string you would need to use an array of longs (long[]) or something more complex.

Comment: If the OP is looking to do the same as the IDE menu, then this method is not the right one to use. (in case of future ppl looking for info)

Answer (score 2):

Returns the first 8 bytes of a SHA1 digest as a long. The same result can be obtained interactively using the BlackBerry JDE by highlighting a string, right-clicking, and choosing "Convert '' to long" from the context menu.

```
long net.rim.device.api.util.StringUtilities.stringHashToLong(String key)
```

Comment: This is the method to use if you want to get the same result as using the IDE menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully grasp your example, but how's this?

```
String match = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("Hrd$457").group();
long longValue = Long.parseLong(match).longValue();
```

Comment: It might not matter for the questioner, but `Long.decode()` will interpret a number starting with a 0 as octal. Perhaps use `Long.parseLong()` instead?

Comment: in which case you don't need `longValue()` either

Comment: @Pål Brattberg i Guess im not explaining my self very well...I need the long value of the entire string, i don't need only the long value of numbers in the string, i need lyrics too in long value.

Comment: @FelipeDev.- Yeah you aren't - mostly because "the long value of the entire string" is no defined concept - if you can't explain what the value should signify there's not much we can do.

Comment: Are you possible talking about a memory address? Or a hash for the String? Again, what is the name of the button in Blackberry? WHat will you use this value for, what is the actual application of this value? Give us details if we are to help!

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach.  If there are multiple numbers you can loop through the String using the scanner.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);
scanner.useDelimiter("\\D+");
Long number = scanner.nextLong();
```

Comment: Like i said in my last comment, i don't need just the numbers of the string, i need that the entire string be convert into float, with alphas inclusive.

Comment: Don't say it in your comment. Rephrase your question so everybody can understand.